# Clicking the add button does absolutely nothing and I dont know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anybody know why the button wont react to input when clicked? I want the click to bring up a prompt and then use the text from the prompt and append it into the hmtl as a list item with the same css as the other list items.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var text = prompt('What do you need to do?')
  var txt1 = $("<li id="
    listItem "><p></p></li>").text(text);
  $("#itemList").append(txt1);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #bff0ff;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#itemList {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#listItem {
  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #5ABCB9;
}

#listItem p {
  font-family: curive, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #
}

.btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #63E2C6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="btn" value="+" />
<ul id="itemList">
  <li id="listItem">
    <p>
      Study for exams.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: missing html, head and script tag that links to jquery library, thats all.

Comment: Also missing a semicolon after your first variable. Wont necessarily break the function, but you should include it regardless (as sometimes automatic semicolon insertion does not work).

Comment: What does the console have to say about this? Also if you are to paste the css could you at least show us you indluded jQuery.

Comment: made no difference

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Where's jQuery? Your code should live inside a document-ready function....

Comment: `$( document ).ready( function () {} );` is not required if you include your code at the end of your page (ideally right before `</body>`) and after jQuery has been included. @aa2397 I converted your code to a Stack Snippet but have not fixed the errors in the JS. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: As I said, the link to jquery isn't in the above code (accident) but it is in my actual html file.

Comment: You have double quotes in your double-quoted string

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add more `li` elements to your existing `ul`, try the following ( since with your current implementation `p` element would be ignored when rendered ) :

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var text = prompt('What do you need to do?')
  var $li = $('<li/>',{ 'class' : 'listItem' })
  var $p = $('<p/>', { 'text' : text })
  $($li).append($p);
  $("#itemList").append($li);
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/9av0c8z3/

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you need to do. First of those should be to clean up the errors in your JS, i.e. this isn't a proper string:

```
"<li id="listItem"><p></p></li>"
```

Once you hit the second double quote (`"`) you're no longer working with a string and it thinks `listItem` is a variable.

I personally use single quotes for strings (`'`).

```
'<li id="listItem"><p></p></li>'
```

Then you'll have to redo how you're using IDs in CSS. IDs should be unique and not re-used, that's what a class is for. So I've changed instances of `id="listItem"` to `class="listItem"` and updated the CSS from `#listItem` to `.listItem`.

Also, when you do this `$( '<li id="listItem"><p></p></li>' ).text( text );` the text gets added to the `li` and the `p` is not created. So create the `p` first, add the text to it then append it to the `li`.

After that I think you're good to go.

```js
var $itemList = $( '#itemList' );

$( '.btn' ).click( function( e ) {

  var text = prompt( 'What do you need to do?' ),
      p    = $( '<p>', { text: text } ),
      li   = $( '<li>', { "class": 'listItem' } ).append( p );
  
  $itemList.append( li );
  
} );
```

```css
body {
  background: #bff0ff;
}

#itemList,
#itemList li {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.listItem {
  width: 250px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #5ABCB9;
}

.listItem p {
  font-family: curive, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background: #63E2C6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="btn" value="+">
<ul id="itemList">
  <li class="listItem">
    <p>
      Study for exams.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```